# Google Adsence balance outpayment below minimum outpayment of 70€

Tags: adsense

I have a Google Adsense balance of 30€ collected within some years and want to stop using Google Adsense since it do not pay of. But the minimum outpayment is 70€. What can I do besides waiting?

Comment: You should contact their support with that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to cancel your account in google adsense you should checkbox that you will not be paid any outstanding earnings visit the [google support](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9914?hl=en).
so I think the best way is to don't cancel your account.

Comment: Your link does help: "If your account balance is greater than the cancellation threshold, make sure that all holds are removed and your account is eligible to receive payments". And the "Payment threshold" is 10€ (https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1709871?visit_id=0-636664085418979497-3983476298&rd=1). So I do can cancel the adsense account *and* get the money :)

Comment: ... and after some weeks I really got the money from google